# moving lists into other lists

Tags: javascript, html

so i have some html like this. ive added some classes for some clarity but their names are irrelevant. on mobile i want "sub-nav" to be a child of the "mobile parent" li. ive got it to appear after the li but not within it in the DOM structure. what am i missing? ive been messing around with the js, hasnt worked.

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-parent><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sub-nav mobile-child">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul

let trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
let nav = document.querySelector('.site-navigation');
let mobileChild = document.querySelector('.mobileChild');
let mobileParent = document.querySelector('.mobileParent');

trigger.addEventListener('click', function(){
    trigger.classList.toggle('active');
    if (trigger.classList.contains('active')) {
        nav.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        if (nav.classList.contains('active')) {
            nav.classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
});

if (window.innerWidth <  768) {
    mobileParent.appendChild(mobileChild);
}
```

Comment: hey mate, can you show the js and css code?

Comment: Or js? If you really want to move it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `media query` to show and hide elements for different devices.

Please refer the below code. And also refer [this post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

```css
.mobile-child-outer{
  display:block;
}
.mobile-child{
  display:none
}
@media screen 
and (device-width: 360px) 
and (device-height: 640px) {
  .mobile-child-outer{
    display:none;
  }
  .mobile-child{
    display:block
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li class="mobile-parent"><a href="#">link 3</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav mobile-child">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sub-nav mobile-child-outer">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Update**
If you want the JS solution try the below. But, I don't think JS is a best solution for this, as you can achieve it with CSS.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", addSubNav);
function addSubNav(){
  var width = document.body.clientWidth;
  if (width <  768) {
     document.querySelector('.mobileParent .mobile-child').remove();
     mobileParent.appendChild(mobileChild);
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont wanna duplicate links. think Js is my only answer

Comment: Technically, when you use JS also you are duplicating the links. Check the updated answer. However, not tested.

Comment: i guess yeah, ideally one piece of markup with no duplicates is what i meant. ill try it and let you know if it works